# How can I add values through XML in OpenERP7?

Tags: xml, postgresql, odoo, openerp-7

I have created a new table called **res.country.region**, and I have also added a new field to the existing table **res.country.state**, this field is **region_id** and indicates to which region a state belongs to.

Now, I am trying to fill in (through a XML file) the field **region_id** for some existing state records, whose *xml_id* are known. This is an example of one of the records of my XML file:

```
<record model='res.country.state' id='ES01'>
    <field name="region_id" ref="l10n_es_toponyms_region.ESPV"/>
</record>
```

The problem is that I am getting an integrity error, because OpenERP7 tells me that I am trying to introduce a record in **res.country.state** with some required fields valueing NULL. And I am not trying to introduce new records, only updating one of their columns.

How can I manage this?

**EDIT**

```
ERROR my_database openerp.sql_db: bad query: insert into "res_country_state" (id,"region_id",create_uid,create_date,write_uid,write_date) values (104,16,1,(now() at time zone 'UTC'),1,(now() at time zone 'UTC'))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/openerp7/ocb-server/openerp/sql_db.py", line 226, in execute
        res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
    IntegrityError: null value in column "code" violates not-null constraint
```

Comment: can you show us integrity error? And note things: when you add value through the xml side, that id is register before using it. For example first define parent value and assign it to child.

Comment: @Odedra Thank you for your answer. I took that into account. I updated my question with the error.

Comment: please insert code value for `res_country_state model,` it's look like code is required field but you didn't give value of it. After that it will work.

Comment: @Odedra Yes, that is the problem I was talking about. I want to update an existing record (which already has code introduced), and I am doing something wrong in the XML records, so OpenERP thinks that I want to create a new state defining only its region_id and leaving code empty. But I want to update, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution: if you want to update a record which was introduced by XML files, yo have to put in its id the name of the module which had the XML file, dot, and the xml_id the record had.

So:

```
<record model='res.country.state' id='module.ES01'>
    <field name="region_id" ref="l10n_es_toponyms_region.ESPV"/>
</record>
```